# Javascript Drop-Down Flashing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a drop-down menu and everything was working fine until I added focusin and focusout.  (I need to be able to tab through the menus, so I was told to add those.)  Now when I use Firefox and select an option from the menu and hold my mouse button on it, it begins to flicker and causes other problems.  Does anyone have a solution to the flickering problem?  Removing focusin and focusout fixes everything, but tabbing no longer works.

Javascript Code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$('#nav')
    .on('mouseenter focusin', '.lv1', function () {
    $(this).find('ul').stop().slideToggle('slow');
})
    .on('mouseleave focusout', '.lv1', function () {
    $(this).find('ul').stop().slideToggle('fast');
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5HaJh/3/

Thank you for the help!!!

Comment: Your fiddle works fine for me with no flicker in Firefox...

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  You have to hold your mouse button down on an option (Test1, Test2, etc.).  We have disabled students who cannot click quickly.

Comment: I can replicate this on Firefox 21.0 on Ubuntu. Works fine with Chrome though. What do you mean tabbing doesn't work anymore if you remove focusin/focusout?

Comment: PherricOxide:  When I remove focusin/focusout, I am unable to tab through the options (Test1 --> Test2 --> Test3).  A few students are unable to use a mouse and have to rely solely on the keyboard.